# Granting privileges to mysql user not working

Tags: mysql, user-permissions

I am logged in to mysql as root. I can add a user like this:

```
CREATE USER test01@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'test01';
```

When I attempt to grant privileges to the `test01` user, nothing seems to happen:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON test_database.* TO 'test01'@'localhost';
```

All of the `*_priv` columns are set to `N` for the `test01` user.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Here are the results of `SHOW GRANTS...`

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test01'@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test01@localhost                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test01'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'removed_hash' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you run `flush privileges` after granting?

Comment: What do `show grants for 'test01'@'localhost';` and `select * from mysql.user;` give you?  (strip the password hashes out of the user table output - it's relevant whether a hash is in the column, but not what it is)

Comment: @quanta - Yes, I did run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after granting.

Comment: @Shane - I just appended the results of `SHOW GRANTS...` to my answer.

Comment: What is the output of `select * from mysql.db where user='test01' and host='localhost' and db='test_database'\G`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> All of the *_priv columns are set to N for the test01 user.

Did you check it from `mysql.user` table, something like this:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user='test01' and host='localhost'\G
```

If so, you're checking in wrong place. All the privileges in this table is **global** privileges, it is assigned by using **on *.***.

While you are granting at **database** level `on test_database.*`, you must check in `mysql.db` table:

```
select * from mysql.db where user='test01' and host='localhost' and db='test_database'\G
```

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html